# How can I reliably test/benchmark the size (including empty buckets) of a .Net HashSet<T> object?

Tags: c#, .net, hashtable, hashset

**As an exercise in personal education and experimentation**, I want to create my own `HashTable` class.  Specifically, I'd like to write this object, without using any existing code (i.e. this object will not inherit from another class) other than mapping to existing interfaces for testing purposes.

Since I'm planning on writing this in C#, my "benchmark" is going to be the .Net `HashSet<T>` class.  I can easily test against the time of execution for add, remove and look-up requests, but I have no clue how to test the size of the `HashSet` benchmark object, *including all buckets that are empty for future add requests*.

How can I track the size of a `HashSet<t>` object as it dynamically grows to make room for future insertions?

To be clear, I don't need to know in the exact number of bytes (I understand that the .Net framework makes it a bit difficult to get the exact size of many types of objects) but rather I'd prefer to know how many buckets are in use and how many are empty, waiting to be used, as I execute various types of test.

Comment: @BartoszKP I specifically stated that I'm not interested in the Size in Bytes.  I want to know how many HashSet buckets exists, whether in use or not.  Big difference.  If they only way I can do this is to grab the size-in-bytes and do the math, then that will suffice.  However, I hope there is a way that I can inspect the HashSet object and grab this information without having to to byte-sized math.

Comment: Ok, I adjusted my wording to clarify.

Comment: Sorry, I changed my wording.  I put the bold comment at the end, because I wanted to avoid the "network effect".  I didn't want lower-level mods to skim my question and simply agree, without catching my final comments.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why the number of buckets in use is a meaningful number for you? I would expect a user of the class to be interested in two things at most: speed, and memory use. Speed you can easily measure. Memory use you can also measure, but not by counting the number of buckets: there is also a fair possibility that your own class's buckets are bigger. I would have expected the total amount of required memory, in bytes, to be a far more meaningful statistic, but my expectation does not seem to match yours.

Comment: Why not extract the code of the existing .NET Hashset with Reflector and then modify it to expose information about size, buckets usage and similar?.. Of course you would use it just for testing purposes.

Comment: @TheZenCoder I hadn't thought of that.  I might try that approach if this information isn't provided by some other method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get the number and size of the buckets is to use reflection. The only trouble is that you need to understand the collection's behavior first. After reading the code a bit and doing some trial and error, it seems you need to count the size of the private `m_buckets` array to get the number of buckets, and count the number of values greater than 0 to get the number of used buckets. The method would look like:

```
static void CountBuckets<T>(HashSet<T> hashSet)
{
    var field = typeof(HashSet<T>).GetField("m_buckets", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic);

    var buckets = (int[])field.GetValue(hashSet);

    int numberOfBuckets = 0;
    int numberOfBucketsUsed = 0;

    if (buckets != null)
    {
        numberOfBuckets = buckets.Length;
        numberOfBucketsUsed = buckets.Where(i => i != 0).Count();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Number of buckets: {0} / Used: {1}", numberOfBuckets, numberOfBucketsUsed);
}
```

To test it, I first created a custom class where I could manually set the hash code:

```
public class Hash
{
    private readonly int hashCode;

    public Hash(int hashCode)
    {
        this.hashCode = hashCode;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.hashCode;
    }
}
```

From there, I did some tests:

```
    var hashSet = new HashSet<Hash>();

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 0 / Used: 0

    var firstHash = new Hash(0);

    hashSet.Add(firstHash);

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 3 / Used: 1

    hashSet.Add(new Hash(1));
    hashSet.Add(new Hash(2));

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 3 / Used: 3

    hashSet.Add(new Hash(3));

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 7 / Used: 4

    hashSet.Add(new Hash(1));

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 7 / Used: 4

    hashSet.Remove(firstHash);

    CountBuckets(hashSet);
    // Number of buckets: 7 / Used: 3
```

It sounds consistent with the intuitive behavior. First, the number of buckets is 0. After adding an element, it's expanded to 3. The number of buckets stay stable until a fourth element is added, expanding the count to 7. When simulating a hash collision, the number of used buckets stay stable, as expected. And removing an element decreases the number of used buckets.

Comment: I knew that `HashSet<T>` objects dynamically grew in size, but I doubted that they would have designed the type to shrink on object removals.  It would be nice if there was fully dynamically sizable HashSet for .Net but I could see it *potentially* being less beneficial than helpful under certain circumstances.

Comment: @RLH `HashSet<T>` already has a `TrimExcess` method, you just need to call it manually (since, like you concluded yourself, it could have negative effects if used incorrectly)

Comment: Now that makes sense.  In fact, now that I've seen it written out, I do recall skimming past that method, looking for some form of bucket count method.

Answer (score 3):

I am not very familiar with internals of `HashSet` but you can [see its source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,2d265edc718b158b) and use Reflection to gets its internal values:

```
HashSet<int> hashSet = new HashSet<int>();
var countField = typeof(HashSet<int>).GetField("m_count", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var freeListField = typeof(HashSet<int>).GetField("m_freeList", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
var count = countField.GetValue(hashSet);
var freeList = freeListField.GetValue(hashSet);
```

*Note:* Such violation of private member access is of course very ugly but in your development/testing phase can be accepted I believe.

Answer (score -2):

thst is interesting questionstrong text... i have a radical suggestion for you:

start your application and get the size of memory before initializing the HashSet. you can do so by using **Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64** (on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.workingset64(v=vs.110).aspx)

then populate your HashSet and print Process.GetCurrentProcess().WorkingSet64 **again**. the difference would be the size you  seek for.

Comment: This isn't reliable for a few reasons.  For one, you never know when the GC will clean up disposed data.  The size of your application can grow and shrink independently of your use of your HashSet (or any collection class.)

Comment: **MaxWorkingSet** will give you the maximum value reached.. that will ignore all the GC cleanups

Comment: BTW You are mentioning working set but your link is pointing to private memory size, which is not the same thing as working set. Working set is physical memory and it is only a subset of private memory...